# Call QSound calls with a delay between them Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, audio, while-loop

Hey I'm building a small game and I am creating the level by making a vector of numbers which correlate to 1-4 colours through a enum. The problem is the loop(in `Simon::loadChallenge`) where I add the color codes to the vector everything works apart from the calls to playSound(which calls `QSound::play`). No sound plays until `Simon::startGame()` finishes then you hear all of the sounds together.

```
auto Simon::playSound(Simon::Color color) -> void {
  if (color == Simon::Color::green) {
    QSound::play(":/sounds/green.wav");
  } else if (color == Simon::Color::red) {
    QSound::play(":/sounds/red.wav");
  } else if (color == Simon::Color::blue) {
    QSound::play(":/sounds/blue.wav");
  } else if (color == Simon::Color::yellow) {
    QSound::play(":/sounds/yellow.wav");
  }
}
```

```
auto Simon::loadChallenge() -> void {
  challengeVect.clear();    <- Clears previous level 
  for (auto i = 0; i < Simon::level; ++i) {
    auto currentVal = static_cast<int>(std::rand() % 4);
    qDebug() << currentVal;
    playSound(Simon::Color(currentVal)); <- Calls method above and is meant to play the sound(doesn't)
    challengeVect.push_back(currentVal);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50)); <- delay which works
  }
}
```

```
auto Simon::startGame() -> void {
  auto i = 10;
  while (i >= 0) { <- If you replace this with while(true) it will run infinitely without playing a sound
    loadChallenge(); <- Where loadChallenge is called from
    --i;
  }
```

I apologise if this isn't enough context the code is here(https://github.com/ItsChoudhry/SimonSaysQt) if you would like a broader look.

Thank you for taking a look at my problem :D

Comment: The [`QSound` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsound.html) states that `QSound` is **asynchronous**, so it makes sense that the sounds do not play immediately when `QSound::play()` is called. Perhaps `QSound` depends on an internal message loop that is blocked by your `startGame()` method. Look at [`QSoundEffect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsoundeffect.html) or [`QAudioOutput`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html), they may be more appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Okay I'll look into the other 2 you mentioned I did try `QSoundEffect` which I think is similar to QSound, but I'll look into it properly and the other one. My logic was QSound is asynchronous so if I put a delay in the main thread the other one won't be blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RemyLebeau for pointing me in the right direction.

While looking into `QSoundEffect` properly I found out about `QEventLoop` combining their forces I have sound and the with delay and everything work in terms of generating levels. These are the changes I made.

```
  // Add this stuff to my constructor
  m_soundEffect = std::make_unique<QSoundEffect>();
  m_soundEffect->setLoopCount(1); <- must set loop count
  m_eventLoop = std::make_unique<QEventLoop>(); <- event loop needed to hear sound
  connect(m_soundEffect.get(), SIGNAL(playingChanged()), m_eventLoop.get(),
          SLOT(quit())); <- needed to stop the event loop after sound is played or program locks up on m_eventLoop .exec()
```

```
//Updated playSound method
auto Simon::playSound(Simon::Color color) -> void {
  if (color == Simon::Color::green) {
    m_soundEffect->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/sounds/green.wav"));
    m_soundEffect->play();
    m_eventLoop->exec();
  } else if (color == Simon::Color::red) {
    m_soundEffect->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/sounds/red.wav"));
    m_soundEffect->play();
    m_eventLoop->exec();
  } else if (color == Simon::Color::blue) {
    m_soundEffect->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/sounds/blue.wav"));
    m_soundEffect->play();
    m_eventLoop->exec();
  } else if (color == Simon::Color::yellow) {
    m_soundEffect->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/sounds/yellow.wav"));
    m_soundEffect->play();
    m_eventLoop->exec();
  }
}
```